# jQuery.datepicker is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I am trying to convert parse date in jquery.
I have a ajax call which return data which have date and int.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: '/varun/dispatcherServlet/myContrller/mymethod',
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json",
   crossDomain: true,
   success: function (data) {
   console.log(data);       
   var processed_json = new Array(); 
   for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      processed_json.push(jQuery.datepicker.parseDate(data[i].myDate),parseInt(data[i].myNumber));
      } 
console.log(processed_json);
```

In the above code I have two *console.log()* the first one

console.log(data);

print the correct data while second one

```
console.log(processed_json);
```

throws an error--

> TypeError: jQuery.datepicker is undefined

`myDtate` and `myNumber` are property in model class.

I have already included ***jquery-1.11.2.min.js***, still i am getting this error. how to resolve this?.

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` right after including jquery, and if you want the styles included aswell (recommended if you're using the datepicker), include this css before your css files: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">`

Answer (score 1):

You also need to include jquery-ui

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js
```